# migrating from @RunWIth(Springrunner::class) to @SpringBootTest with an H2 database (Junit4 to Junit5)

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I'm upgrading spring-boot in a large project, and as a result the tests must be migrated from Junit4 to Junit5. From migration guides it sounded easy enough. Essentially, what I read over and over again was to replace this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
```

with this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
```

The problem is, while this works for simple cases, the two don't seem to be equivalent in more complex aspects, and I can't find any migration guides for those specific cases.
In our specific example, we're running an H2 database for tests, and we have a data.sql file in the test resources to initialise the database. With SpringRunner, this was picked up by convention, fed into the DB, and everything worked.

Now with Junit5 and @SpringBootTest, apparently there's no such luck. The database is empty, and the context load fails.

So what do I need to do to get that feature back?